# How to delete the first line of match by sed

Tags: sed

I have file like this,then now I want to delete only the first `def_xxx`

```
abc_xxx
def_xxx
ghi_xxx
abc_yyy
def_yyy
ghi_yyy
```

It delete the two lines `def_xxx`,`def_yyy`.

```
sed -e '/def/d' myfile.txt
```

How can I delete the only first line `def_xxx`??

Comment: Use the full pattern. If you have a `def_www` before `def_xxx`, simply using `def` will fail.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e '0,/def/{/def/d;}' myfile.txt
```

This deletes the first occurrence of the pattern.

From its manual:

```
0,addr2
Start out in "matched first address" state, until addr2 is found. This is similar
to 1,addr2, except that if addr2 matches the very first line of input the 
0,addr2 form will be at the end of its range, whereas the 1,addr2 form will 
still be at the beginning of its range. This works only when addr2 is a 
regular expression.
```

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed

Comment: May as well provide the full `def_xxx` in case there is actual a larger file with other `def` prefixed lines -- but good answer.